# Android - extending an activity,can't change layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

i want to extend an existing Activity changing its layout and i'm trying to do this:

```
public class NewActivity extends ParentActivity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.new_layout);

     ...
}
```

but it doesn't work; the old layout appears!
On the other hand if I do this:

```
public class NewActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.new_layout);
    ...
}
```

then it works..why??

ParentActivity's onCreate():

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    setTitle(R.string.title_home);      
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.home);
....
}
```

Comment: Please show the ParentActivity's onCreate(). Nevertheless, both pecies of code you posted should result in the Activitys layout being "new_layout"

Comment: Post your `ParentActivity`.

Comment: ParentActivity is over 400 lines of code..i've quoted just a part of it...any idea?